# avoid records with the same data

Tags: php, mysql

by means of an if attempt that can not be created two records with the same name, it does not work and you can create a record with a dupiclate name

this is the controller

```
include_once 'model/solucion.php';

public function Guardar()
{
    $this->model->Duplicado($_POST['Nombre']);
        $name = $this->model->resultado2['Nombre'];
        if($name == $_POST['Nombre']){
       die("No se puede crear una solucion con el mismo nombre");
       }else{
        $solucion = new solucion();    
        $solucion->id = $_REQUEST['id'];

        $solucion->Nombre = $_REQUEST['Nombre'];
        $solucion->Tipo = $_REQUEST['Tipo'];
        $solucion->Descripcion = $_REQUEST['Descripcion'];

        $solucion->Pagina = $_FILES['Pagina']['name'];
        }
    header("Location: index.php");
  }
```

this is the model

```
public $resultado2;

public function Duplicado($Nombre)
{
    try {


        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM fallas WHERE Nombre = '$Nombre'");
        $stm->execute();
        $res=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->resultado2 = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($res as $row)
        {
            $this->resultado2[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];

            $this->resultado2[$i]['Nombre'] = $row['Nombre'];
            $this->resultado2[$i]['Tipo'] = $row['Tipo'];
            $this->resultado2[$i]['Descripcion'] = $row['Descripcion'];
            $this->resultado2[$i]['Pagina'] = $row['Pagina'];
            $i++;
        }

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
}
```

this is the view

```
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
 <li><a href="?c=solucion&a=Paginar">Inicio</a></li>
 <li class="active"><?php echo $solucion->id != null ?
 $solucion->Nombre : 'Nueva Solución'; ?></li>
 </ol>

 <form id="frm-alumno" action="?c=solucion&a=Guardar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $solucion->id; ?>" />

 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="Nombre" value="<?php echo $solucion->Nombre; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" required>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Tipo de fallo</label>
 <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="Tipo" value="<?php echo $solucion->Tipo; ?>">
  <option value="software">software</option>
  <option value="hardware">hardware</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>

</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Descripcion</label>
    <textarea type="text" name="Descripcion" value="<?php echo $solucion->Descripcion; ?>" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="40" required>
    </textarea>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label>Pagina.php</label>
    <input type="file" name="Pagina" value="<?php echo $solucion->Pagina; ?>" >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label >Imagenes</label>

        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="archivo[]" name="archivo[]" multiple="" >

</div>
<hr />
<br>
<div class="text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
</div>
```

What do I have to change in the controller to avoid creating duplicate records with the same name?

Comment: Try this `$name = $this->model->resultado2[0]['Nombre'];` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the array and check whether this is empty or not . Check below for the code and run it and let me know if you get any error .

```
public function Duplicado($Nombre)
{
    try{
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM fallas WHERE Nombre = '$Nombre'");
        $stm->execute();
        $res=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $res;
    }catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($e->getMessage());
     }
}



include_once 'model/solucion.php';

public function Guardar()
{
    $name = $this->model->Duplicado($_POST['Nombre']);
    //$name = $this->model->resultado2['Nombre'];
    if(!empty($name)){
        die("No se puede crear una solucion con el mismo nombre");
    }else{
         $solucion = new solucion();    
         $solucion->id = $_REQUEST['id'];
         $solucion->Nombre = $_REQUEST['Nombre'];
         $solucion->Tipo = $_REQUEST['Tipo'];
         $solucion->Descripcion = $_REQUEST['Descripcion'];
         $solucion->Pagina = $_FILES['Pagina']['name'];
     }
    header("Location: index.php");
 }
```